# How Can Wordpress Easily Provide A Voting and Commenting View For 5 Page Layout Possibilities?

Tags: wordpress, content-management-system, media

Right now, when I create a media item, I can view it as admin by going through the Media then clicking on view, eventually I end up at `[mysite]/blog/?attachment_id=31` which is a nice reduced version of the image (which can be clicked to appear large), and which has the nice feature that there is a place to leave comments at the bottom.

This is great for administrators. But I want anonymous users to be able to look at 5 different, fairly similar images, and make comments on the pages separately. So I'd like for the anonymous users who navigate to `[mysite]/blog/?attachment_id=31` to find the same page the way it looks to admins.

But when going to that URL as an anonymous user instead of the image with comment form I get:

> Sorry, no posts matched your criteria

So, how can I enable this permission for anonymous users?

If this is not possible, please rephrase the question as, "What is the best way to use Wordpress to get a bunch of anonymous people to vote on 5 different layouts and also to be able to comment on each of them separately, as I am trying to do at `http://christian-filipina.com/blog/` ? (None of these are public URLs, please don't link to them.)

Do I need to create a page for each of those separate layouts and then use HTML to link to the variously-sized versions of the images?

Answer (score 0):

When adding an image to the post make sure that "attachment page" is checked instead of "image file" This should fix your problem. See: http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Image_and_File_Attachments

Comment: Thanks to your suggestion I realized that the file also needs to be included in a different way.  I couldn't find the attachment page check you mention, but what I did was on the main page referencing the 5 media sub-pages, I clicked "Add Media" at the top. Then it inserted html code with additional [] pseudo-html, and for whatever reason, that also triggered the image files to be visible for anonymous guests.

Comment: Are you using a plugin to display images? Also what version of WordPress? In 2.8.6 if you go to the post page and click on the "add media" or if media is already there "edit media" you'll see a radio with the options to "link to media" or "link to attachment page". Looks like you got it working though. ;) as an side-note you can also have an attachment.php template if you want the attachment pages to have a different look.

Comment: Yes, I have the latest version - now that I take a clearer look, you're right, my media option was also set to link to attachment page. But that wasn't enough: using the "add media" from the edit page of a published blog entry was also required, to make the media pages visible to guests.

Comment: How were you inserting media before, I would always recommend the "add media" and "library" functions of WordPress.